# Is it mentioned anywhere in the Quran that Shaithan came with Adam to Earth from Paradise?

Tags: quran, tafseer, shaitan

I just want to know if any verse in the Quran mentions that Shaithan came with Adam to Earth from Paradise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of verses which can be used as an evidence for the exodus from Paradise, for example you may read it in surat al-Baqara in the verse, but you should read it in context to the verses before:

> But **Satan** caused **them** to slip out of it and removed them from that [condition] in which they had been. And We said, "**Go down, [all of you], as enemies to one another**, and you will have upon the **earth a place of settlement and provision** for a time." ([2:36](http://legacy.quran.com/2/36))

This verse shows that earth will be their destination and place of stay for the rest of their lives.
And later in the same surah Allah () says:

> We said, "**Go down from it**, all of you. And when guidance comes to you from Me, whoever follows My guidance - there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve. ([2:38](http://legacy.quran.com/2/38))

in surat al-'Araaf again earth is mentioned as the destination for settlement:

> [ Allah ] said, "**Descend**, being to one another enemies. And for you **on the earth is a place of settlement** and enjoyment for a time." ([7:24](http://legacy.quran.com/7/24))

and in surat Taha:

> [ Allah ] said, "**Descend from Paradise** - all, [your descendants] being enemies to one another. And if there should come to you guidance from Me - then whoever follows My guidance will neither go astray [in the world] nor suffer [in the Hereafter]. ([20:123](http://legacy.quran.com/20/120-126))

all these verses must be read in context.